# Does this statement in model theory hold?

Tags: proof-explanation, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a class of finite $\mathcal{L}$-structures and $T=\text{Th}(\mathcal{K})$.

> If $T$ admits an infinite model then $T$ admits finite models of arbitrarily large cardinal.

Let suppose that $T$ has an infinite model. But as $T=\text{Th}(\mathcal{K})$ we can deduce that $T$ also admits finite models. Then I do not know how to make a link between the infinite model and the finite models of $T$ ?

Notice that, at the end we want to prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a model of $T$, $\mathfrak{R}$ such that $\vert R \vert\ge n$.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you mean that $T = Th(\mathcal{K})$?

Comment: @MarkSaving, My bad typo ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element of the class $\mathcal{K}$ is a finite model of the theory $T=\mathrm{Th}(\mathcal{K})$. So if $\mathcal{K}$ contains finite structures of arbitrarily large cardinality, then $T$ admits finite models of arbitrarily large cardinality, and we're done.

Otherwise, there is a bound $B \in \mathbb{N}$ so that the class $\mathcal{K}$ does not contain finite structures of size larger than $B$. But then take a first-order sentence $\varphi$ which states "the structure has no more than $B$ elements". Clearly, this sentence $\varphi$ holds in every structure in the class $\mathcal{K}$, and consequently $\varphi$ belongs to the theory $T$. But an infinite model of $T$ would have more than $B$ elements, which would contradict $\varphi$. Therefore, $T$ does not have infinite models.

Taking contrapositives, we get that if $T$ does have an infinite model, then $T$ also has finite models of arbitrarily large cardinality (and the class $\mathcal{K}$ that  we started with contains such models).

Comment: Thank you for the precision ! For the sentence $\varphi$ is it linked to $\theta_n : \exists x_1,...,\exists x_n \bigwedge (x_i \neq x_j) ; \ n\ge 2$ ?

Comment: Yes, closely related. Your $\theta_B$ would assert that there *are* $B$ different elements. You want $\varphi$ to assert the exact opposite: out of any $B+1$ elements $x_0, \dots, x_B$, at least two are the same.